# Transformation Matrix4f or to Quaternion [Minecraft 21w18a Fabric]

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-fabric

After fabric update (from 1.16 to 21w18a), some code stopped working, namely
`RenderSystem.multMatrix(matrixStack.peek().getModel());`
This call stopped working because the function is no longer there. Is there any replacement for this function or a way to convert matrixStack to Quaternion?

#### all code

```
public void renderFinders(MatrixStack matrixStack) {

        // RenderSystem.pushMatrix(); // 1.16
        matrixStack.push();

        RenderSystem.multMatrix(matrixStack.peek().getModel()); // 1.16 FIX IT

        GlStateManager._disableTexture();
        // GlStateManager.disableTexture(); // 1.16

        GlStateManager._disableDepthTest(); 
        // GlStateManager.disableDepthTest(); // 1.16

        DiamondGen.gen.simOreGen.render();

        // RenderSystem.popMatrix(); // 1.16
        matrixStack.pop();
    }
```